# How can I update my 3 tables using my viewmodel in ASP.NET Core MVC (I already have the Create)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

So firstly, I have Parent, Student and Current Year Student tables, a student requires a parent so obviously that would needed to be added first before the rest. **My Problem is how I can change the Edit/UpdateStudent Action Result to edit the data in my database, using my ViewModel.**

**This is my View Model:**

```cs
 public class StudentParentViewModel
    {

        //parent
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Contact_Number { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Alt_Contact_Number { get; set; }
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        public string Home_Address { get; set; }
        public int ParentTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Parent_Name { get; set; }
        public string Parent_Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Parent_Surame { get; set; }
        public long PID_Number { get; set; }

        //student
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DoB { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool Remember { get; set; }
        public int Student_TypeID { get; set; }
        public string Student_Name { get; set; }
        public string Student_Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Student_Lastname { get; set; }
        public long SID_Number { get; set; }

        //current year student
        public int CurrentYearStudentID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> GradeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ClassID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> YearID { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Create, where the user adds the 3 above mentioned entities to their relative tables in the database all at one on one view.

**This is my Create Action Method**

```
  // GET: Students/Create
        public ActionResult RegisterStudent()
        {
            ThorntreeDatabaseEntities db = new ThorntreeDatabaseEntities();
            ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(db.ParentTypes, "Parent_TypeID", "Parent_Type");
            ViewBag.Student_TypeID = new SelectList(db.StudentTypes, "Student_TypeID", "Student_Type");
            ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(db.Classes, "ClassID", "Class_Name");
            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(db.Grades, "GradeID", "Grade_Name");
            ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(db.Years, "YearID", "Year1");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Students/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public ActionResult RegisterStudent(StudentParentViewModel studentParentViewModel)
        {

            ThorntreeDatabaseEntities db = new ThorntreeDatabaseEntities();
            List<Class> ClassList = db.Classes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(ClassList, "ClassID", "Class_Name");

            List<Grade> GradeList = db.Grades.ToList();
            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(GradeList, "GradeID", "Grade_Name");

            List<Year> YearList = db.Years.ToList();
            ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(YearList, "YearID", "Year1");

            List<StudentType> TypeList = db.StudentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.Student_TypeID = new SelectList(TypeList, "Student_TypeID", "Student_Type");

            List<ParentType> ParentList = db.ParentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(db.ParentTypes, "Parent_TypeID", "Parent_Type");
            //Parent 
            Parent parent = new Parent();
            parent.Title = studentParentViewModel.Title;
            parent.Parent_Name = studentParentViewModel.Parent_Name;
            parent.Parent_Middle_Name = studentParentViewModel.Parent_Middle_Name;
            parent.Parent_Surame = studentParentViewModel.Parent_Surame;
            parent.Home_Address = studentParentViewModel.Home_Address;
            parent.PID_Number = studentParentViewModel.PID_Number;
            parent.Contact_Number = studentParentViewModel.Contact_Number;
            parent.Alt_Contact_Number = studentParentViewModel.Alt_Contact_Number;
            parent.Email_Address = studentParentViewModel.Email_Address;
            parent.ParentTypeID = studentParentViewModel.ParentTypeID;
            db.Parents.Add(parent);
            db.SaveChanges();

            int latestParentID = parent.ParentID;

            Student student = new Student();
            student.Student_Name = studentParentViewModel.Student_Name;
            student.Student_Middle_Name = studentParentViewModel.Student_Middle_Name;
            student.Student_Lastname = studentParentViewModel.Student_Lastname;
            student.DoB = studentParentViewModel.DoB;
            student.SID_Number = studentParentViewModel.SID_Number;
            student.Gender = studentParentViewModel.Gender;
            student.Student_TypeID = studentParentViewModel.Student_TypeID;
            student.ParentID = latestParentID;
            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();

            int latestStudentId = student.StudentID;

            CurrentYearStudent current = new CurrentYearStudent();
            current.ClassID = studentParentViewModel.ClassID;
            current.GradeID = studentParentViewModel.GradeID;
            current.YearID = studentParentViewModel.YearID;
            current.StudentID = latestStudentId;
            db.CurrentYearStudents.Add(current);
            db.SaveChanges();
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ViewStudents");
            }
            return View(studentParentViewModel);

        }
```

**This is where I have the edit button, it is on my ViewStudents.cshtml. It is using the CurrentYearStudents model so I cant access the ParentID:**

```cs
@model IEnumerable<Thorntree_Primary_School_INF_370_System.Models.CurrentYearStudent>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Students";
}


<html>
<head>
    <style>
        input[type="text"] {
            position: center;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        input[type="file"] {
            position: center;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        button[type="submit"] {
            position: center;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #tableHeadder {
            display: table-header-group;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <h3>World</h3>

    <div class="container" style="outline:solid">
        <button class="btn bg-primary" style="">Back</button>

        <div @*style="text-align:center"*@>
            <h1>View Students</h1>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewStudents", "Student", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                //the following are search options
                <b> Search Option: </b>@Html.RadioButton("option", "FirstName") <label>Name</label> @Html.RadioButton("option", "Grade") <label>Grade</label>
                @Html.RadioButton("option", "Class")<label>Class</label> @Html.RadioButton("option", "None") <label>None</label> @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
            }
            <table class="table table-dark">
                <thead id="tableHeadder">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Grade</th>
                        <th scope="col">Class</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.Student_Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.Student_Lastname)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade.Grade_Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class.Class_Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateStudent", new { id = item.StudentID }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CurrentYearStudentID })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***This is how my 3 tables look inside SQL Server***

[image]

I could really use some assistance, I've been at this problem for 2 days now and to no avail.

If you would like to see my update action you may ask, however its almost identical to the add one but just commented out, I don't know how to go about moving on... Please please please help, I'm at a loss right now, its not often I look for help. (Just who I am :( )

**Edit View:**

```cs
@model Thorntree_Primary_School_INF_370_System.Models.StudentParentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update Student";
}


@*<html>
<head>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>


    <h4>Parent of Student</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Title" class="control-label col-md-2">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Title } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Contact_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Contact Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Contact_Number } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Alt_Contact_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Alternative Contact Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt_Contact_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Alt_Contact_Number } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt_Contact_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email_Address" class="control-label col-md-2">Email Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email_Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Email_Address } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email_Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Home_Address" class="control-label col-md-2">Home Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Home_Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Home_Address } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Home_Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ParentTypeID" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ParentTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.ParentTypeID })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Parent_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parent_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Parent_Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Parent_Middle_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Middle Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parent_Middle_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Parent_Middle_Name } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Middle_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Parent_Surame" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Surname</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parent_Surame, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Parent_Surame } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Surame, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PID_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent ID Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PID_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.PID_Number } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PID_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="DoB" class="control-label col-md-2">Date of Birth</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.DoB } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="DoB" class="control-label col-md-2">Gender</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Gender } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_TypeID" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Type</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Student_TypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_TypeID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_TypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_Name } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_Middle_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Middle Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_Middle_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_Middle_Name } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_Middle_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_Lastname" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Surname</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_Lastname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_Lastname } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_Lastname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SID_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Student ID Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SID_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.SID_Number } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SID_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Register</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="GradeID" class="control-label col-md-2">Enrollment for Grade</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("GradeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.GradeID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GradeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ClassID" class="control-label col-md-2">Enrollment for Class</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ClassID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.ClassID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="YearID" class="control-label col-md-2">Enrollment for Class</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("YearID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.YearID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}

<div>
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ViewStudents")</button>

</div>
```

**This is my current Update Action result (Yes probably very wrong but it does get the StudentID to edit)**

```
         public ActionResult UpdateStudent(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }       

            ThorntreeDatabaseEntities db = new ThorntreeDatabaseEntities();

           

            List<Class> ClassList = db.Classes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(ClassList, "ClassID", "Class_Name");

            List<Grade> GradeList = db.Grades.ToList();
            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(GradeList, "GradeID", "Grade_Name");

            List<Year> YearList = db.Years.ToList();
            ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(YearList, "YearID", "Year1");

            List<StudentType> TypeList = db.StudentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.Student_TypeID = new SelectList(TypeList, "Student_TypeID", "Student_Type");

            List<ParentType> ParentList = db.ParentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(db.ParentTypes, "Parent_TypeID", "Parent_Type");

            StudentParentViewModel viewModel = new StudentParentViewModel();

            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(student.ParentID);

            db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == parent.ParentID);
            viewModel.Title = parent.Title;
            viewModel.Parent_Name = parent.Parent_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Middle_Name = parent.Parent_Middle_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Surame = parent.Parent_Surame;
            viewModel.Home_Address = parent.Home_Address;
            viewModel.PID_Number = parent.PID_Number;
            viewModel.Contact_Number = parent.Contact_Number;
            viewModel.Alt_Contact_Number = parent.Alt_Contact_Number;
            viewModel.Email_Address = parent.Email_Address;
            viewModel.ParentTypeID = parent.ParentTypeID;
            viewModel.ParentID = parent.ParentID;

            int latestParentID = parent.ParentID;
            viewModel.StudentID = student.StudentID;
            viewModel.Student_Name = student.Student_Name;
            viewModel.Student_Middle_Name = student.Student_Middle_Name;
            viewModel.Student_Lastname = student.Student_Lastname;
            viewModel.DoB = student.DoB;
            viewModel.SID_Number = student.SID_Number;
            viewModel.Gender = student.Gender;
            viewModel.Student_TypeID = student.Student_TypeID;
            student.ParentID = latestParentID;

            int latestStudentId = student.StudentID;


            db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == parent.ParentID);
            viewModel.Title = parent.Parent_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Name = parent.Parent_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Middle_Name = parent.Parent_Middle_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Surame = parent.Parent_Surame;
            viewModel.Home_Address = parent.Home_Address;
            viewModel.PID_Number = parent.PID_Number;
            viewModel.Contact_Number = parent.Contact_Number;
            viewModel.Alt_Contact_Number = parent.Alt_Contact_Number;
            viewModel.Email_Address = parent.Email_Address;
            viewModel.ParentTypeID = parent.ParentTypeID;


            CurrentYearStudent current = new CurrentYearStudent();
            viewModel.ClassID = current.ClassID;
            viewModel.GradeID = current.GradeID;
            viewModel.YearID = current.YearID;
            viewModel.StudentID = latestStudentId;




            ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(db.ParentTypes, "Parent_TypeID", "Parent_Type");
            ViewBag.Student_TypeID = new SelectList(db.StudentTypes, "Student_TypeID", "Student_Type");
            ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(db.Classes, "ClassID", "Class_Name");
            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(db.Grades, "GradeID", "Grade_Name");
            ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(db.Years, "YearID", "Year1");
            return View(viewModel);
        }

 // POST: Students/Update/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UpdateStudent(StudentParentViewModel viewModel)
        {

            ThorntreeDatabaseEntities db = new ThorntreeDatabaseEntities();
            List<Class> ClassList = db.Classes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ClassID = new SelectList(ClassList, "ClassID", "Class_Name");

            List<Grade> GradeList = db.Grades.ToList();
            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(GradeList, "GradeID", "Grade_Name");

            List<Year> YearList = db.Years.ToList();
            ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(YearList, "YearID", "Year1");

            List<StudentType> TypeList = db.StudentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.Student_TypeID = new SelectList(TypeList, "Student_TypeID", "Student_Type");

            List<ParentType> ParentList = db.ParentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(db.ParentTypes, "Parent_TypeID", "Parent_Type");


                Parent parent = new Parent();
                parent.Title = viewModel.Title;
                parent.Parent_Name = viewModel.Parent_Name;
                parent.Parent_Middle_Name = viewModel.Parent_Middle_Name;
                parent.Parent_Surame = viewModel.Parent_Surame;
                parent.Home_Address = viewModel.Home_Address;
                parent.PID_Number = viewModel.PID_Number;
                parent.Contact_Number = viewModel.Contact_Number;
                parent.Alt_Contact_Number = viewModel.Alt_Contact_Number;
                parent.Email_Address = viewModel.Email_Address;
                parent.ParentTypeID = viewModel.ParentTypeID;


                int latestParentID = parent.ParentID;

                Student student = new Student();
                student.Student_Name = viewModel.Student_Name;
                student.Student_Middle_Name = viewModel.Student_Middle_Name;
                student.Student_Lastname = viewModel.Student_Lastname;
                student.DoB = viewModel.DoB;
                student.SID_Number = viewModel.SID_Number;
                student.Gender = viewModel.Gender;
                student.Student_TypeID = viewModel.Student_TypeID;
                student.ParentID = latestParentID;


                int latestStudentId = student.StudentID;

                ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(db.Parents, "ParentID", "Title", student.ParentID);

                CurrentYearStudent current = new CurrentYearStudent();
                current.ClassID = viewModel.ClassID;
                current.GradeID = viewModel.GradeID;
                current.YearID = viewModel.YearID;
                current.StudentID = latestStudentId;
                db.CurrentYearStudents.Add(current);


                ViewBag.Student_TypeID = new SelectList(db.StudentTypes, "Student_TypeID", "Student_Type", student.Student_TypeID);

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.Entry(current).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("ViewStudents");
                }
                return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Comment: May I know your expectations here? What exactly you want to update into the 3 tables from your view model? You mean this `StudentParentViewModel` viewModel? if so where is the view of it?

Comment: Add neccessary information so that your issue can be reproducible easity. This question  hard to reproduce as it has many dependency which has not been included. Try to add sample to load your `RegisterStudent` view and `edit` context so that it would be much easier to show you next steps where you are stuck in.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron So i am trying to update All the details from the Student table, then the details of the parent that student belongs to as well as what Grade, class and year the student is in, only the CurrentYearStudent Table gets displayed to my view. I have added the view for the edit page, where they change their details.

Comment: If it  can be reproduciable then it might be easier to point your problem

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron so what does someone need to reproduce this as it stands? my CreateStudent View? my current non working Update action result?

Comment: Its mean if someone can copy your code on their environment in a way so that they can easity reach to the point of error or the place where exactly you are struggling at. Because if it has many dependency and enough information has not given then contributor might not interested to invest effort on that. For better clarity , you can have a look on few of my answer, you can just test it simply by coping it on your environment. So that you needn't to go through  trial and error process which eventually save your efforts.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have added a few more snippets so that maybe just maybe someone can help me

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I got something in my update action result which seems to now display the details of the student and its parent and currentYearStudents inside the update view, however i have no idea why my Http Post: is not working

Comment: Please have a try the solution and let me know if that resolve your problem accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well lets start with your comment below..

***"However I have no idea why my Http Post: is not working"***

Its because of your this code `@using (Html.BeginForm())` instead it should be like `@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "controllerName"))`

***How can I update my 3 tables using my viewmodel:***

Please follow the steps below

***Student Model To Load List First:***

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string DoB { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public bool Remember { get; set; }
    public string Student_Name { get; set; }
    public string Student_Middle_Name { get; set; }
    public string Student_Lastname { get; set; }
    public long SID_Number { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudentType")]
    public int StudentTypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Grades")]
    public int GradeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Year")]
    public int YearID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClassType")]
    public int ClassTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentType StudentType { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Grades Grades { get; set; }
    public virtual Year Year { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassType ClassType { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller For Loading Students List:***

I am not sure which approach you are using for binding data `database first` or `code first`. I am binding data from database like below:

```
   public IActionResult GetAllStudents()
        {
            var obj = _context.Students.Include(st => st.StudentType).Include(pt => pt.Parent).Include(y => y.Year).Include(ct => ct.ClassType).ToList();
            return View(obj);
        }
```

***View For Student List:***

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCApps.Models.Student>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DoB)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Remember)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student_Middle_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student_Lastname)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SID_Number)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parent.Parent_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GradeID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YearID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClassTypeID)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DoB)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Remember)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student_Middle_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student_Lastname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SID_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.Parent_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentType.StudentTypeName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grades.GradeName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year.YearName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClassType.ClassTypeName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateStudentById", new { id = item.StudentID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> ***Note:***  For loading this view I am using your `student` domain class.

***Output:***

[image]

***Update Operation:***

When you would click on edit button it should load your view with `viewmodel` type.
so where we will use your `StudentParentViewModel`

***View Model:***

```
public class StudentParentViewModel
    {
        //parent
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Contact_Number { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Alt_Contact_Number { get; set; }
        public string Email_Address { get; set; }
        public string Home_Address { get; set; }
        public int ParentTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Parent_Name { get; set; }
        public string Parent_Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Parent_Surame { get; set; }
        public long PID_Number { get; set; }

        //student
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool Remember { get; set; }
        public int StudentTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Student_Name { get; set; }
        public string Student_Middle_Name { get; set; }
        public string Student_Lastname { get; set; }
        public long SID_Number { get; set; }

        //current year student
        public int CurrentYearStudentID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> GradeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ClassTypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> YearID { get; set; }
    }
```

***Update Controller:***

When you would click on a `edit` button it will hit the controller with a specific `id`. So here we will bind the `ViewModel` after getting the details information by that `id` and return the view for loading `update view`

```
  public ActionResult UpdateStudentById(int? id)
        {
            //Get student by ID
            var studentObject = _context.Students.Include(st => st.StudentType).Include(pt => pt.Parent).Where(sid => sid.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            //Bind Dropdown
            List<StudentType> studentType = _context.studentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.StudentTypeID = new SelectList(studentType, "StudentTypeID", "StudentTypeName");

            //Bind ParentType Dropdown
            List<ParentType> parentTypeList = _context.ParentTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(parentTypeList, "ParentTypeID", "ParentTypeName");

            //class type
            List<ClassType> classType = _context.classTypes.ToList();
            ViewBag.ClassTypeID = new SelectList(classType, "ClassTypeID", "ClassTypeName");
            //grade
            List<Grades> grades = _context.Grades.ToList();
            ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(grades, "GradeID", "GradeName");

            //class type
            List<Year> years = _context.Years.ToList();
            ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(years, "YearID", "YearName");

            //Bind to View Model
            StudentParentViewModel viewModel = new StudentParentViewModel();

            //Student student = _context.Students.Find(id);
            //  Parent parent = _context.parents.Find(parent.ParentID);

            //db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentID == parent.ParentID);
            viewModel.Title = studentObject.Parent.Title;
            viewModel.Parent_Name = studentObject.Parent.Parent_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Middle_Name = studentObject.Parent.Parent_Middle_Name;
            viewModel.Parent_Surame = studentObject.Parent.Parent_Surame;
            viewModel.Home_Address = studentObject.Parent.Home_Address;
            viewModel.PID_Number = studentObject.Parent.PID_Number;
            viewModel.Contact_Number = studentObject.Parent.Contact_Number;
            viewModel.Alt_Contact_Number = studentObject.Parent.Alt_Contact_Number;
            viewModel.Email_Address = studentObject.Parent.Email_Address;
            viewModel.ParentTypeID = studentObject.Parent.ParentTypeID;
            viewModel.ParentID = studentObject.Parent.ParentID;

            int latestParentID = studentObject.Parent.ParentID;
            viewModel.StudentID = studentObject.StudentID;
            viewModel.Student_Name = studentObject.Student_Name;
            viewModel.Student_Middle_Name = studentObject.Student_Middle_Name;
            viewModel.Student_Lastname = studentObject.Student_Lastname;
            viewModel.DoB = Convert.ToDateTime(studentObject.DoB);
            viewModel.SID_Number = studentObject.SID_Number;
            viewModel.Gender = studentObject.Gender;
            viewModel.StudentTypeID = studentObject.StudentTypeID;
            studentObject.ParentID = latestParentID;

            int latestStudentId = studentObject.StudentID;



            return View(viewModel);
           
        }
```

***Update View:***

```
@model MVCApps.Models.StudentParentViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateStudent", "Student"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <h4 style="color:white">Parent of Student</h4>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group" hidden>
            <label for="DoB" class="control-label col-md-2">StudentID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.StudentID } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="DoB" class="control-label col-md-2">Date of Birth</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.DoB } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="DoB" class="control-label col-md-2">Gender</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Gender } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_TypeID" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Type</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("StudentTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.StudentTypeID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_Name } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_Middle_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Middle Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_Middle_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_Middle_Name } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_Middle_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Student_Lastname" class="control-label col-md-2">Student Surname</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student_Lastname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Student_Lastname } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student_Lastname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SID_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Student ID Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SID_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.SID_Number } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SID_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <h4>Parent of Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group" hidden>
            <label for="Title" class="control-label col-md-2">StudentID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.ParentID } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Title" class="control-label col-md-2">Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Title } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Contact_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Contact Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Contact_Number } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Alt_Contact_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Alternative Contact Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt_Contact_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Alt_Contact_Number } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt_Contact_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email_Address" class="control-label col-md-2">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email_Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Email_Address } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email_Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Home_Address" class="control-label col-md-2">Home Address</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Home_Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Home_Address } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Home_Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ParentTypeID" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Type</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ParentTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.ParentTypeID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Parent_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parent_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Parent_Name } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Parent_Middle_Name" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Middle Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parent_Middle_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Parent_Middle_Name } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Middle_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Parent_Surame" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent Surname</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Parent_Surame, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.Parent_Surame } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Parent_Surame, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="PID_Number" class="control-label col-md-2">Parent ID Number</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PID_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.PID_Number } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PID_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Register</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="GradeID" class="control-label col-md-2">Enrollment for Grade</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("GradeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.GradeID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GradeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ClassID" class="control-label col-md-2">Enrollment for Class</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ClassTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.ClassTypeID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="YearID" class="control-label col-md-2">Enrollment for Class</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("YearID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @value = Model.YearID })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @Html.ActionLink("List", "GetAllStudents", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

***Output of Upate View:***

[image]

***Update Controller:***

When update view would be loaded, after neccessary update we will hit update button which will send the updated data to `UpdateStudent` controller with our `StudentParentViewModel` like below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UpdateStudent(StudentParentViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //If either of this is empty then add
        if (viewModel.StudentID == 0 && viewModel.ParentID == 0)
        {
            //Add Or Create 
            //Bind Student
            var student = new Student();
            student.Student_Name = viewModel.Student_Name;
            student.Student_Middle_Name = viewModel.Student_Middle_Name;
            student.Student_Lastname = viewModel.Student_Lastname;
            student.Gender = viewModel.Gender;
            student.StudentTypeID = viewModel.StudentTypeID;
            student.ParentID = viewModel.ParentID;
            student.DoB = viewModel.DoB.ToString();
            student.GradeID = viewModel.GradeID??0;
            student.ClassTypeID = viewModel.ClassTypeID??0;
            student.YearID = viewModel.YearID??0;
            student.ClassTypeID = viewModel.ClassTypeID??0;


            _context.Students.Add(student);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            //Bind Parent

            Parent parent = new Parent();
            parent.Title = viewModel.Title;
            parent.Parent_Name = viewModel.Parent_Name;
            parent.Parent_Middle_Name = viewModel.Parent_Middle_Name;
            parent.Parent_Surame = viewModel.Parent_Surame;
            parent.Home_Address = viewModel.Home_Address;
            parent.PID_Number = viewModel.PID_Number;
            parent.Contact_Number = viewModel.Contact_Number;
            parent.Alt_Contact_Number = viewModel.Alt_Contact_Number;
            parent.Email_Address = viewModel.Email_Address;
            parent.ParentTypeID = viewModel.ParentTypeID;
            _context.parents.Add(parent);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            var findStudent = _context.Students.Find(viewModel.StudentID);
            //Bind to student table
            Student objStudent = new Student();
            findStudent.Student_Name = viewModel.Student_Name;
            findStudent.Student_Middle_Name = viewModel.Student_Middle_Name;
            findStudent.Student_Lastname = viewModel.Student_Lastname;
            findStudent.DoB = viewModel.DoB.ToString();
            findStudent.SID_Number = viewModel.SID_Number;
            findStudent.Gender = viewModel.Gender;
            findStudent.StudentTypeID = viewModel.StudentTypeID;
            findStudent.ParentID = viewModel.ParentID;
            findStudent.ClassTypeID = viewModel.ClassTypeID??0;
            findStudent.GradeID =(int) viewModel.GradeID;
            findStudent.ParentID = viewModel.ParentID;

            //Bind the parent table
            var findParent = _context.parents.Find(viewModel.ParentID);
            Parent objParent = new Parent();
            findParent.Title = viewModel.Title;
            findParent.Parent_Name = viewModel.Parent_Name;
            findParent.Parent_Middle_Name = viewModel.Parent_Middle_Name;
            findParent.Parent_Surame = viewModel.Parent_Surame;
            findParent.Home_Address = viewModel.Home_Address;
            findParent.PID_Number = viewModel.PID_Number;
            findParent.Contact_Number = viewModel.Contact_Number;
            findParent.Alt_Contact_Number = viewModel.Alt_Contact_Number;
            findParent.Email_Address = viewModel.Email_Address;
            findParent.ParentTypeID = viewModel.ParentTypeID;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        //Bind Dropdown
        List<StudentType> studentType = _context.studentTypes.ToList();
        ViewBag.StudentTypeID = new SelectList(studentType, "StudentTypeID", "StudentTypeName");

        //Bind ParentType Dropdown
        List<ParentType> parentTypeList = _context.ParentTypes.ToList();
        ViewBag.ParentTypeID = new SelectList(parentTypeList, "ParentTypeID", "ParentTypeName");

        //class type
        List<ClassType> classType = _context.classTypes.ToList();
        ViewBag.ClassTypeID = new SelectList(classType, "ClassTypeID", "ClassTypeName");
        //grade
        List<Grades> grades = _context.Grades.ToList();
        ViewBag.GradeID = new SelectList(grades, "GradeID", "GradeName");

        //class type
        List<Year> years = _context.Years.ToList();
        ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(years, "YearID", "YearName");
       // return Redirect()
        return RedirectToAction("GetAllStudents");
    }
```

***Note:*** Like `Student` and `Parent` table you can bind your view model data to `Nth` number of table like the way I have shown above. Finally redirect the update page to list page.

***Final Output:***

[image]

> ***Note:*** I have found some inconsistency in your code which you could improve, like if class property you write as `Parent_Name` then
> follow the `under score` convention every where. If `camel case`
> `parentName` then `camel case` every where, like wise `pascal case`
> `ParentTypeID` then follow that every where which reduce code smells and
> make the code more readable.

Hope above steps will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I will forever remember your name as the MY SAVIOUR, i will take note with the naming conventions. From the bottom of my heart thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Just a quick other point, i think where you say `_context.Students.Add(student);` and `_context.parents.Add(parent);`  so for these 2 lines I think it is causing the data to add an entry with tthe new update as apposed to updating it. Do you perhaps know the problem? @Md Farid Uddin Kiron

Comment: At the beginning you can notice at update method, I checked for student and parent id, it means when we create new student and parents there would be no id at that time, so when there would a Id means we are updating and when no id means need to add. Just check the logic yourself and let me know your feedback.

Comment: I have tried to used update method both for adding and update request. You can make it separate so that there would be no challenge.

Comment: You can ommit `if` part and remove `else` and keep the code inside the `else` part which only work for update. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I understand the logic behind it now but its throwing an error with `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
findStudent was null.` As well as im not too sure but you're not making use of the variables: `objStudent` and `objParent`

Comment: check the property name is same with the model, debug it, did you get `StudentID` on update?

Comment: What do you mean (I'm sorry if I'm being dumb) The `objStudent` and `objParent` are just the names of your variable, they create the new Student and Parent object prefectly fine, but they are not used anywhere thought the code.

Comment: Hope your problem resolved, even you encountred any furhter problem, feel free to post new question.